# GCP: How to install and run "google-ip-forwarding-daemon" service in VM instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I have created a VM instance in GCP from my custom image. My objective is to check IP Aliasing using this vm of gcp. IP aliasing is not working for me. After refering some documents it seems that aliasing is not working because "google-ip-forwarding-daemon" service is not working. following is the excerpt from the document:

```
Ensure that ip_alias = true in /etc/default/instance_configs.cfg. If you have to change 
this, you must also restart the routing daemon:
service google-ip-forwarding-daemon restart


"/etc/default/instance_configs.cfg" does not exist in my vm.
```

Following services are running in my vm:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep google
snap-google\x2dcloud\x2dsdk-235.mount   enabled         enabled
google-guest-agent.service              masked          enabled
google-osconfig-agent.service           enabled         enabled
google-oslogin-cache.service            static          enabled
google-shutdown-scripts.service         masked          enabled
google-startup-scripts.service          masked          enabled
google-oslogin-cache.timer              enabled         enabled
```

It does not have daemon service running.

any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**google-ip-forwarding-daemon** is used to forward TCP packets.

That feature is enabled if you enable **IP Forwarding** when you create the VM. IP Forwarding cannot be enabled once the VM is running.

Comment: how to enable IP Aliasing in VM instance? I dont see instance_configs.cfg even after creating VM with --can-ip-forward. is there other way to enable IP Aliasing?

Comment: @Manomugdha - Your original question has been answered. Please create a new post for a new problem. Even though the problems are related for you, one item per post on Stack Overflow.